# Show that if $u$ is a solution of the ODE $u'(x)+Q(x)u(x)=0$ and has a zero, then it vanishes

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $I\subset\mathbb{R}$ be an open interval and $Q\colon I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function.
Show that if $u$ is a solution of the ODE $u'(x)+Q(x)u(x)=0$ such that $u(x_0) = 0$ for some $x_0\in I$ then $u\equiv 0$ on $I$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Which ODE do you mean? $u'\equiv 0$? (You can find a tutorial for MathJax here to help you write the formulas: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: ODE is y' +Q(x)y = 0.

Comment: This is just an immediate consequence of Picard-Lindelöf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot appeal to Picard-Lindelöf, write your DE as $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(u(x)e^{\int_{x_0}^xQ(s)\mathrm{d}s}\right)=0$$ This means $$u(x)e^{\int_{x_0}^xQ(s)\mathrm{d}s}=c$$ for some constant $c$. Taking $x=x_0$ implies $c=0$ and so $$ u(x)e^{\int_{x_0}^xQ(s)\mathrm{d}s}=0 $$ for all $x\in I$. But $e^{\int_{x_0}^xQ(s)\mathrm{d}s}$ is never $0$ which means $u(x)=0$ and we're done.